# installing old packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone 
i am new to ros , i always meet packages that i need and  that have not recent release , i was wondering if it is possible to install old packages in a new ros version
ps: for now i am trying to install smach_viewer which is only avalable for ros indigo (i am using kinetic)
thank you in advence

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258270/installing-old-packages/) by [2fik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29515/2fik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can generally install old packages from source; I recommend you search for other answers and tutorials about how to install packages from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2fik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29515/2fik/) on 2017-03-31**:
ok thank you